# How to import src module to public folder in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-cloud-messaging

As I'm using `Firebase Cloud Messaging` in my `React`, it requires me to put the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in my public folder.

In there, it is defining the function for the `onBackgroundMessage`, which I want to have an access to my module, and update some of my components in my src.

```
import { toast } from "react-toastify"; // or import my other modules
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log('Received background message ', payload);

  //toast or do some updating my modules
  toast(`Message received : ${payload}`) // here comes the error 
});
```

But I got an error of

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at
> firebase-messaging-sw.js:3:1)

How can I import my src module to the public folder?

How should I properly use the `onBackgroundMessage` in React?

is it normal to import module from src to the public folder?

Answer (score 0):

Use [importScripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) to import scripts into the worker's scope like firebase-messaging itself.

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.0/firebase-messaging.js');
```

Comment: Then what should be the correct path to my src folder? can it access my src folder directly like `importScripts ('/src/example.js')` ?